# IntelliJ installing breakpoint on a line > 65536 not possible

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to install a breakpoint in a large java file with IntelliJ after the line 65536 (2^16) which turns out to be impossible. The breakpoint is marked with a "X" and the tooltip says there is no executable code.

Is there any IntelliJ or java option to solve the issue? The idea.max.intellisense.filesize is already increased.

I am on a 64Bit Java 8u144 VM, running on IntelliJ 2018.1.4. The class file is inside a maven packed .war file and running inside a JBoss EAP 7

Comment: Usually, one would ask you to provide your code, but 65536 lines will be hard to read.... Do you really have a single .java file that has 65536 lines of code?

Comment: And more importantly: Would it be possible to split code out of the file to bring it below 2^16 lines?

Comment: How you managed to create such monstrosity? Anyway, you should probably use JetBrains bugtracker for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: Well, I thought I would get such answers like "think about your class design". But the class is kind of.. lets say legacy code. It is automatically transformed from COBOL code and the COBOL source contains already 21k lines. So splitting the class is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JVM doesn't like large java class files.

From the JVM spec:

> 4.7.12. The LineNumberTable Attribute
>   The LineNumberTable attribute is an optional variable-length attribute in the attributes table of a Code attribute (§4.7.3). It may be used by debuggers to determine which part of the code array corresponds to a given line number in the original source file.
>
> If multiple LineNumberTable attributes are present in the attributes table of a Code attribute, then they may appear in any order.
>
> There may be more than one LineNumberTable attribute per line of a source file in the attributes table of a Code attribute. That is, LineNumberTable attributes may together represent a given line of a source file, and need not be one-to-one with source lines.
>
> The LineNumberTable attribute has the following format:

```
LineNumberTable_attribute {
u2 attribute_name_index;
u4 attribute_length;
u2 line_number_table_length;
{   u2 start_pc;
    u2 line_number; 
} line_number_table[line_number_table_length];
}
```

The fact that the start_pc and line_number are "u2" type
(unsigned, 2 byte ints) means that line number information
is not defined after the source line index is greater
than 2^16 = 65536.